# EOFError when input() after print() in SSH console

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, console, eoferror

I got a strange behavior in my Python code. It runs fine in my Windows console

For example,

@cmd.exe : python *file.py*

Content of my *file.py* file

```
print("-------------------------- RANDOM STRING HERE! --------------------------------")
email = input()
print("-------------------------- RANDOM STRING HERE! --------------------------------")
name = input()
print("-------------------------- RANDOM STRING HERE! --------------------------------")
address = input()
print("-------------------------- RANDOM STRING HERE! --------------------------------")
print(email+name+address)
```

This same code doesn't work when I do:

```
curl ://filepath/file.py | sudo python3
```

in an a console under SSH. I already tried with [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) and Git Bash, but I am still getting the same error.

EOFError in SSH Console:

[image: EOFError in SSH Console]

I already tried to use sys.stdin, but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You are loading the script over stdin. Python has already read it all and there is nothing more available.

Comment: @ephemient searched and understood in someway how stdin works.. i still can't get the user's input under those consoles.. tried sys.stdin.read() => nope and sys.stdin.buffer.raw.read(100), works in cmd but nope via ssh.. (unlimited field and doesn't submit when pressing enter) .. Is there any way expected to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, really, you can't do that this way. Running

```
... | sudo python3
```

puts the script to the `stdin` so you can't use the `stdin` from that script any more.

But you can do it the other way round without a pipe using a temporary file:

```
curl ://filepath/file.py -o /tmp/script
sudo python3 /tmp/script
```

Or using process substitution (in Bash):

```
python3 <(curl ://filepath/file.py)
```

Comment: Makes sense! Partially worked using process substituion (doesn't work with sudo) returns for some reason: **python3: can't open file '/dev/fd/63': [Errno 2] No such file or directory** and **(23) Failed writing body**, temporary file doesn't work either resulting **curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sudo curl: (6) Could not resolve host: python3 curl: (3) <url> malformed** -- syntax error? Upvoted and i lack some reputation, Thanks @Jakuje !

Comment: Yes. Obviously the `sudo` closes all the additional file descriptors (which is a good security practice, but breaks this use case). Without sudo it can work.